# Springfox not generating Swagger docs for Spring MVC Rest versioned API

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-2.0

We are facing our REST API versioning and after having read a lot about the different options (URI versioning, mime type versioning) have decided to use the latter approach.

I was expecting that Springfox generates the following doc:

**v1:**

```
get /api/architecture/mails - application/vnd.arch.mails.v1+json 
get /api/architecture/services - application/vnd.arch.service.v1+json
```

**v2:**

```
get /api/architecture/services - application/vnd.arch.service.v2+json
```

However, in the v2 I also get this:

```
get /api/architecture/services - application/vnd.arch.service.v1+json
```

It shouldn't be there since I configured the v2 Docklet with 
`.produces(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"application/vnd.arch.service.v2+json"})))` so that it filters the services according to the versioned mime type. Why isn't is working?

Here is our **springfox config**:

```
    @Bean
    public Docket arqV1Api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/architecture/.*"))               
            .build()
            .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Architecture Rest Api","Architecture REST Services","v1","","","",""))
            .produces(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"application/vnd.arch.service.v1+json","application/vnd.arch.mail.v1+json"})))
            .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
            .groupName("Arq v1 group");
    }


    @Bean
    public Docket arqV2Api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/architecture/.*"))               
            .build()
            .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Architecture Rest Api","Architecture REST Services","v2","","","",""))
            .produces(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"application/vnd.arch.service.v2+json"})))
            .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
            .groupName("Arq v2 group");
    }
```

And these is the **REST Controller**:

```
private static final String serviceArqV1MediaType = "application/vnd.arch.service.v1+json";
private static final String serviceArqV2MediaType = "application/vnd.arch.service.v2+json";
private static final String mailsArqV1MediaType   = "application/vnd.arch.mail.v1+json";

@ApiOperation(value = "Gets architecture services", 
              notes = "",
              produces = serviceArqV1MediaType)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Request OK"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request")})
@RequestMapping(value = {"/services"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = serviceArqV1MediaType)
public List<ServicioArquitectura> getServices() {
    return Arrays.asList(new ServiceArch[]{new ServicioArquitectura("Support"), new ServicioArquitectura("Kickoff")});
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Gets architecture services", 
          notes = "",
          produces = serviceArqV2MediaType)
@ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Request OK"),
      @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request")})
@RequestMapping(value = {"/services"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = {serviceArqV2MediaType})
public List<ServicioArquitecturaV2> getServicesV2() {
    return Arrays.asList(new ServiceArchV2[]{new ServiceArchV2("Support", Boolean.TRUE), new ServiceArchV2("Kickoff", Boolean.FALSE)});
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Gets mails", 
          produces = mailsArqV1MediaType)
@ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Request OK"),
      @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request")})
@RequestMapping(value = {"/mails"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = {mailsArqV1MediaType})
public List<String> getMails() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"xxxcompany.com"});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/965) in Springfox's github and they pointed out how to correctly configure it. Here's the solution:

**Helper static methods**:

```
 public static Predicate<RequestHandler> withMediaType(final MediaType[] mediaTypes){
    return new Predicate<RequestHandler>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(RequestHandler input) {
            if(mediaTypes!=null){
                ProducesRequestCondition producesCondition = input.getRequestMapping().getProducesCondition();
                Set<MediaType> producibleMediaTypes = producesCondition.getProducibleMediaTypes();
                for (MediaType mt : producibleMediaTypes) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mediaTypes.length; i++) {
                        if(mt.equals(mediaTypes[i])){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}

public static Set<String> mediaTypesToStringSet(MediaType[] mediaTypes){
    Set<String> mediaTypesSet = new HashSet<String>();
    if(mediaTypes!=null){
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaTypes.length; i++) {
            mediaTypesSet.add(mediaTypes[i].toString());
        }
    }
    return mediaTypesSet;
}
```

**Docket definitions:**

```
@Bean
public Docket arqV1Api() {
    MediaType[] validMediaTypes = new MediaType[]{new MediaType("application","vnd.arch.service.v1+json"),
                                                  new MediaType("application","vnd.arch.mails.v1+json")};
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(withMediaType(validMediaTypes))
        .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/architecture/.*"))               
        .build()
        .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Architecture Rest Api","Architecture REST Services","v1","","","",""))
        .produces(mediaTypesToStringSet(validMediaTypes))
        .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey()))
        .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
        .groupName("Arq v1 group");
}
@Bean
public Docket arqV2Api() {
    MediaType[] validMediaTypes = new MediaType[]{new MediaType("application","vnd.arch.service.v2+json")};
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(withMediaType(validMediaTypes))
        .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/architecture/.*"))               
        .build()
        .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Architecture Rest Api","Architecture REST Services","v2","","","",""))
        .produces(mediaTypesToStringSet(validMediaTypes))
        .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey()))
        .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
        .groupName("Arq v2 group");
}
```